# What is my program in Selenium not stopping executing?

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I built my Selenium test cases in Maven, and the following in my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "webdriver/chromedriver");
       WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
       driver.get("https://localhost:4502");
       driver.quit();
}
```

My chromedriver was downloaded and moved to a folder called "webdriver" in the project. Once the program is lauched, the chrome browser is opened and then closed.

However, even after the chrome browser is closed, and "driver.quit()" is executed, why is the not exit and terminates its execution?

Comment: So the application stays running even after the browser quits?

Comment: yes, you're totally right. @GregBurghardt

Comment: Cant you get  error for  variable driver?

Comment: Which version of ChromeDriver and Chrome are you using?

Comment: the current chromedriver version is 80.0.3987.106/  @GregBurghardt

Comment: @DipakBachhav I don't have error for the variable driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why it is happening. But, I can use `System.exit(1)` to exit the program.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



  String folder_path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
  System.out.println(folder_path);
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
  folder_path+"\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
                WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  driver.quit();

}
```

In your example above you should get compile time exception instead of running session.

Comment: I did what what you said. But the error said the "The driver executable does not exist:" in the path, although the path is correct and the chrome driver DOES exist there.

Comment: String folder_path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",folder_path+"/webdriver/chromedriver.exe");

                                                                                                                      
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: check your chrome driver version aligned with chrome browser and if its latest then i would suggest give a restart to clear ports

Comment: Can you write again, how are you writing the driver implementation  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "webdriver/chromedriver"); exactly as this line? or you modified it? if so can you edit your question?

Comment: Pretty much the same, except the I have "driver.get("https://localhost:4502");" which I just added to the question. Besides what you have just told me, I also downloaded the newest version of chromedriver, it did not work either.